# barplot axis label sizes not controlled by cex.axis

Tags: r

This seems like unexpected behavior.

```
barplot(table(sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE)),cex.axis=3)
```

[image]

The xaxis size isn't controlled by `cex.axis`. Anyone have an explanation for that and know how to adjust the xaxis label size? Thanks

Comment: Look at `?barplot`. You need `cex.names` for the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in `?barplot`, the character expansion argument for the x-axis (or the y-axis if `horizontal=TRUE`) is `cex.names`.

```
barplot(table(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)), cex.axis=3, cex.names=3)
```

[image]